# Define route for specific URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, culture

My ASP.NET MVC 5 project is multilingual and I use culture to change the language.

I have defined the default routing with culture as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var _cul = CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture() != null
            ? CultureHelper.GetCurrentCulture()
            : ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["WebSiteDefaultCulture"];

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{culture}/{Controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {culture = _cul, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "{culture}/Home/{action}/{id}",
            new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}
```

So the URL of all pages of the site will be opened only with culture.

I want to open some specific site URLs without culture.

For example, this URL `https://test.com/en-US/Cart/Cart/5` can be opened without providing a culture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define two routing, with and without culture

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultWithCulture",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = _cul }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { culture = _cul, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```